# AES encryption in JAVA and decryption in C using openSSL causing issue

Tags: java, c++, openssl, aes, libcrypto

I am using below JAVA code to encrypt plain text, which will create cipher text, later decrypt this cipher text using Key ( which is generated via getSecretEncryptionKey().getEncoded() in JAVA File ) in C++ code.

JAVA CODE:

```
    public byte[] encryptDecrypt(String jsonData, String publicKey) throws Exception
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        SecretKey secKey = getSecretEncryptionKey();

        cipherText = encryptText(jsonData, secKey);
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static SecretKey getSecretEncryptionKey() throws Exception
    {
        KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        generator.init(256);
        SecretKey secKey = generator.generateKey();
        return secKey;
    }
    public static byte[] encryptText(String plainText, SecretKey secKey) throws Exception
    {
        // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secKey.getEncoded(), "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");

        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        return  aesCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
    }
```

C++ CODE:

```
INT32 Security::decrypt(UINT8 *ciphertext, INT32 ciphertext_len, UINT8 *key,
                UINT8 *iv, UINT8 *plaintext)
{
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

  INT32 len;

  INT32 plaintext_len;

  /* Create and initialise the context */
  if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

if (!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ecb(), 0, key, NULL)) {
        printf("\n ERROR!! \n");
                return -1;
     }

  /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
   * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
   */
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
    handleErrors();
  plaintext_len = len;

  /* Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
   * this stage.
   */
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
  plaintext_len += len;

  /* Clean up */
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

  return plaintext_len;
}
```

While decrypting CipherText using Key , C++ code is generating segmentation fault and giving below error:

**140159077054088:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:596:
Aborted (core dumped)**

I am new in this domain so please help me.

Comment: 1. Provide sample data: key, plaintext, cipher text, decrypted text. Simplified sample text instead of JCON would make things easier. 2. Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: Also this code is not C. Check your tags. It is also strange you actually do have initialization vector parameter but you do not use it. You are also using Key instead of key as your key.

Comment: @brank0 Thanks, I updated my TAG and I mistakenly updated "Key" to "key".

Comment: @zaph, Right now, I can not provide you sample data. I will give you by tomorrow. Meanwhile  Can you give me any example, which encrypts plain text in JAVA and decrypts it into C++, using same library? Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I fixed this problem by referring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835158/aes-256-cbc-in-java